# what's better to use for a python 2.7.X amazon client - boto or boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

i'm using `boto3` to use amazon's kms services.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.kms_client = boto3.client('kms')

def encrypt_text(self, text):
    response = self.kms_client.encrypt(
        KeyId = self.global_key_alias,
        Plaintext = text
    )
    return response['CiphertextBlob']

def decrypt_text(self, encrypted_text):

    # official docs state that encrypted_text should be a byte(doesn't exists in python 2)
    # currently it's working when sending a string, but it's dangerous
    response = self.kms_client.decrypt(
        CiphertextBlob = encrypted_text
    )
```

I'm using boto3 since the new feature will be developed there.

as the note's say, i'm send a string instead of the official docs that states that you need to send a byte type.

I'm wondering if this could change in the future? and then My api to amazon will be useless since i'm don't have `bytes` type in python 2.7.9

Any comments ? ideas?

Comment: We do not know how Amazon will change their client API in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where are these "official docs" you are referring to?  A pointer would be helpful.

I think this is really a question about compatibility between Python 2.x and 3.x.  In Python 2.x, a `byte` is really a `str`.  In Python 3.x, there is an actual `bytes` type.

You could use the [six](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) package to help you smooth over these differences between Python versions.  In six, there is a `six.binary_type` that maps to `str` in Python 2.x and `bytes` in Python 3.x.

I don't think you have to worry about your code not working with a future version of boto3 but you do need to worry about it working with Python 3.x sometime in the future.